# Enabling Background Playback: How can I integrate Spotify to play songs directly within a mobile app?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, spotify

I'm currently working on a mobile app project (frontend in react-native and backend in nodeJS) with the goal of allowing users to play Spotify songs directly within the app, and specifically, in the background seamlessly. The objective is to enhance the user experience by eliminating the need for manual play actions within the Spotify app.

There is an API : https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api

I do not have took a look on the android-api yet, I told myself that if I had a back Node I'd need the web api.

I have successfully used these docs to generate a link that redirects to Spotify on my PC. However, it only takes me to the track page without playing the sound. Additionally, I've obtained a link suitable for an 'audio' element, but it provides a preview_url with a duration of 30 seconds and sometimes returns as 'null'. I want to emphasize that this is on a PC, not on a mobile device. If anyone has insights, solutions, or ideas on how to achieve background playback or has encountered a similar situation, I would greatly appreciate your assistance!

```
const express = require("express");
const { SpotifyApi } = require("@spotify/web-api-ts-sdk");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(cors());

const api = SpotifyApi.withClientCredentials(
  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
);

app.get("/testSpotify", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const trackId = "7J1uxwnxfQLu4APicE5Rnj?si=7ec56c19fc924afe";
    const trackInfo = await getTrackInfo(trackId);
    const trackUrlPreview = trackInfo.preview_url;
    const trackUrlSpotify = trackInfo.external_urls.spotify;
    res.json({ trackUrlPreview, trackUrlSpotify });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});

async function getTrackInfo(trackId) {
  const response = await api.tracks.get(trackId);
  return response;
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Music Player</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="getTrack()">
    <audio id="musicPlayer" controls></audio>
    <a href="" id="goSpotify">Go Spotify</a>
    <script>
      const musicPlayer = document.getElementById("musicPlayer");
      const goSpotify = document.getElementById("goSpotify");

      async function getTrack() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/testSpotify");

          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
          }

          const data = await response.json();
          console.log(data);
          musicPlayer.src = data.trackUrlPreview;
          goSpotify.href = data.trackUrlSpotify;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error.message);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need *app remote*: https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/app-remote-lib/docs/ in order to control Spotify app.

Also, Spotify broadcasts some intents that you may listen to.